# pyinstaller -- script not found.

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to learn how to use pyinstaller to make an executable. I wrote a little script  in 2.7 as a test. Print 'test" and named it test-print. When I click on the executable in the Build folder a cmd screen flashes, and that all she wrote. I tried adding a x = raw_input('input something: ') hoping that would cause the cmd screen, or some kind of screen to persist, but to no avail. I know this is basic stuff, but a voice of experience would be most helpful.
F

Comment: OK Dist was the ticket. Somewhere else someone said to run the .exe from the Build folder.

Comment: That was very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Now when I run the executable, a cmd console opens and asks my dumb raw_input question. When I type something, the characters are printed by my print statement and the cmd console instantly disappears. Is there a way to cause the cmd screen to persists? I tried an infinite loop but that didn't help. I was kind of thinking the .exe would open in a window and not the cmd console?  here's my code:                                                                                                           import time
x = str(raw_input('input something: '))
print x
while True:
    time.sleep(5)

Comment: Under Dist I drilled down to the Test-Print Folder and ran the application from that folders, and it works just fine. Why does pyinstaller create so many applications with my file name? I found at least 3; one in the Build folder, one in the Dist folder, and one in the Dist>Test-Print folder. Only the app in the Dist>Test-Print folder works properly.

Answer (score 0):

First try running the command from a command line (terminal) so you can see what happens.  Not from inside any IDE.

If you created the script in a MSWindows environment, be sure your PATH includes the executable (or explicitly give the path to the script).

In Linux/Unix, be sure to enable execute permission for the script.  `chmod +x` *scriptname*

Answer (score 0):

In pyinstaller the actual executable is located in the dist folder. I assume you did not use pyinstallers "--onefile" switch so once you finish compiling, navigate to dist then test-print. Afterwards look for test-print.exe in that folder. That is your executable.

Comment: Does the "-onefile" switch put the .exe in the Build folder? Now I'm trying to understand why there is a .exe in Build?

Comment: no what the onefile switch does is pack the exe into a singe file. Without the onefile switch you would have a large bundle of files that the exe uses. With the onefile switch, the entire exe is packed into one file